# Assign types to argument of generic mapping function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a function which maps over an array. It looks like this:

```
// opt is either `statusA` | `statusB`
options.map((opt: keyof StatusType) => {
        const activeStatus = statusCollection[opt]; //typescript doesnt scream `of any type` error
        ...
```

where, StatusType looks like:

```
type Keyys = 'statusA' | 'statusB';

export type StatusType = {
  [key in Keyys]: boolean;
};
```

I did this because i want to be able to retrieve computed property from an object, to store in 'activeStatus' variable above.

This would work fine if the options is always of the type `statusType`, however, it being an generic function, I want to be able to pass in other collections. How would I define the `type` to replace the 'StatusType' to be more generic & to avail the `keyof` feature correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right track. All I did was create a type for containing the different type definitions using OR `|`. And passing that as `keyof` of string type.

```
type TypeContainer = StatusTypeA | StatusTypeB;

options.map((opt: keyof sype) => {
        const activeStatus = statusCollection[opt as keyof TypeContainer];
```

Hope this helps.